# Showing data in a form in .NET with Postgres

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I tried to use this code to show data from a database in a form but I got an error in the DataAdapter.Fill, I tried to delete it but nothing appears when I execute the program, I don't know what else can I do. Here you have the code and the screenshot of the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/faQ32.png

```
public partial class ShowData : Form
    {
        public ShowData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=firstdatabase;User Id=postgres";                      
            conn.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM first_schema.customers";

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);           

            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            NpgsqlDataAdapter ad = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();


            while (dr.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                    Console.Write("{0} \t \n", dr[i].ToString());
            }

            ad.Fill(dt);
            // ad.Fill(ds);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} \t \n", row[i].ToString());
                }
            }


            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to close `dr`(`dr.close()`) before `ad.Fill(dt);`

Comment: Has your while clause been completed when the exception is thrown? Is your Console.Write command normally executed?

Comment: Remove the `while (dr.Read())` loop.

Comment: If I run it without the while loop I don't get errors but the form is empty.

Comment: You haven't shown any code where the values are shown on the form. Is `dt.Rows` populated with the data?

Comment: The database has data, when I run the program the data is showed in the console below, but not in the form.